# import edgetpu.detection.engine ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'edg

Tags: edge-tpu

I have successfully Installed EdgeTPU and Coral according to `GoogleCoral` https://coral.ai/docs/accelerator/get-started/#2-install-the-pycoral-library
But somehow there is still error: no module named 'edgetpu'
Yes, I've also tried this.
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-edgetpu...
Please see the result below.
######pycoral result##############3

```
pi@raspy:~/coral/pycoral $ python3 

examples/classify_image.py \
--model test_data/mobilenet_v2_1.0_224_inat_bird_quant_edgetpu.tflite \
--labels test_data/inat_bird_labels.txt \
--input test_data/parrot.jpg
----INFERENCE TIME----
Note: The first inference on Edge TPU is slow because it includes loading the model into Edge TPU memory.
18.4ms
5.1ms
6.1ms
5.6ms
5.3ms
-------RESULTS--------
Ara macao (Scarlet Macaw): 0.75781

#################################
pi@raspy:~/DeepPiCar/models/object_detection $ python3 

    code/coco_object_detection.py
    **Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/pi/DeepPiCar/models/object_detection/code/coco_object_detection.py", line 9, in <module>
        import edgetpu.detection.engine
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'edgetpu'**

###############################
pi@raspy:~ $ sudo apt-get install python3-edgetpu

    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree... Done
    Reading state information... Done
    Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
    requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
    distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
    or been moved out of Incoming.
    The following information may help to resolve the situation:
    
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     python3-edgetpu : Depends: python3 (< 3.9) but 3.9.2-3 is to be installed
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```